# Cannot create priviledged containers

Tags: kubernetes

I am using instructions from https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/getting-started-guides/docker-multinode.md to setup a multinode kubernetes cluster on vmware vcloud infrastructure.

I was able to get the cluster working but when I tried the [nfs example](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/examples/nfs) I was not able to create the nfs container. So I recreated all the VMs and rebuilt kubernetes from source using:

```
git clone https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes.git
cd kubernetes
sed -i 's/allow_privileged: .*/allow_privileged: true/g' cluster/saltbase/pillar/privilege.sls
./build/run.sh hack/build-cross.sh
cp _output/dockerized/bin/linux/$(dpkg --print-architecture)/kubectl /usr/local/bin
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/kubectl
```

and continued to setup the kubernetes cluster and retried the NFS example and I get the following error:

```
kubectl create -f nfs-server-pod.yaml 
The Pod "nfs-server" is invalid.
spec.containers[0].securityContext.privileged: forbidden '<*>(0xc20931650c)true'
```

I tried with both the `master` and `1.0.3` release and had the same result.

Can you please tell me how to resolve this issue and Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

We thought that turning privileged containers off by default would be good for security.  It turns out to just be a pain point for a lot of people, so we're working to turn it on by default in kubernetes v1.1.

The `--allow-privileged` flag has to be set on both the kubelet and the apiserver - please check that

Comment: With kubernetes 1.1.0 out, does it now allow privileged containers by default?

Comment: v1.1 is not out yet - we have cut a stabilization branch, but not made a release.